# Android 10: Difference Between System, Product and Vendor Partition

Tags: android, frameworks, partitioning, platform

Android has read only A/B partitions where different apps are preloaded by OEM:

```
/system/app
/system/priv-app
/product/app
/product/priv-app
/vendor/app
/vendor/priv-app
```

Questions:

1. What is privilege/permissions difference between all above file path?
2. OEMS App, SOC Manufactures Apps and Third Party Apk are preloaded in which partitions?